# Difference between sudo make and sudo -s ; make

Tags: sudo, make

What are the differences between

```
sudo make
```

and

```
sudo -s
make
```

First example do not work with my software, there is always a header file missing.
Login as root with `sudo -s` and compile works fine.

So what are the differences, wherefore `sudo make` is not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sudo -s` runs the command as root in a shell referenced by the environment variable `SHELL`

`sudo` runs the command as root in the same shell as the original user

Comment: but I dont understand the differences for make, could you clarify that?

Comment: make depends on shell environment variables like PATH, HOME, LANG. If you change of shell those variables are different and can cause problems.

Comment: Usually the software is installed using sudo (for example: "sudo apt-get installl ..."), then the installation of the software modifies the PATH of the user; meanwhile the PATH of root keeps unchanged. root's shell lacks of information that has been integrated in the user environment.

Comment: ok just tried it on PATH example: `sudo echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games` and `sudo -s ; echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin`